# ¿Cómo se manejan las llaves foráneas de la base de datos MySQL, en un proyecto en Spring boot con Java?

Tags: java, spring

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java con Sprin boot. Esoy desarrollando un proyecto escolar en el que debemos crear models, DAO, Service, Service Implementation y Controllers. Al crear el controller de una clase me genera el siguiente error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'cotizacion0_.idClientes' in 'field list'
```

Creo que se debe a unas llaves foráneas que tengo en esa tabla y no se cómo definirlas en el modelo, el DAO, el servicio, la implementación del servicio ni en el controlador.

Gracias por la ayuda de la comunidad.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Deberías agregar el código donde generas la consulta o donde quizas esté ocurriendo el error. Por lo que deduzco, la consulta que estás haciendo está mal. El tipo de error es SQLGrammarException, por lo tanto parece error es de la consulta (sin se experto en springboot).

Comment: Hola Oscar, seria bueno que agregues el codigo de las entity relacionadas, y nos muestres el schema de tus tablas relacionadas en el error

Comment: Gracias por la pornta respuesta. Voy a agregar el código de las entidades relacionadas de manera inmediata.